# Are there only 16 digits in a sum of decimal

Tags: informix

```
create table t (mnt decimal(20,2));
insert into t values (111340534626262);
insert into t values (0.56);
select sum(mnt) from t;
select sum(mnt::decimal(20,2))::decimal(20,2) from t;
```

I can't get more than 16 digits. Any idea?

Using IDS 12.10FC10.

Comment: Seem to be a limitation of dbaccess in displaying large numbers. Check the documentation on the environment variable `DBFLTMASK`: [DBFLTMASK environment variable](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_14.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_216.htm)  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run the code shown in my [`sqlcmd`](http://www.iiug.org/software/) program, I get the output:

```
111340534626262.56
111340534626262.56
```

When I run the code shown in Informix's DB-Access program, I get this output (slightly altered):

```
           (sum) 

 111340534626263

1 row(s) retrieved.        

    (expression) 

 111340534626263

1 row(s) retrieved.
```

The problem, therefore, is probably in the display mechanism in DB-Access rather than in the server itself.

If you're writing your own code, it is relatively straight-forward to ensure that the display is accurate and complete.  Using DB-Access is not necessarily the best way to go.

Comment: Informix CQ idsdb000104759.